# Superuser access in shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, root

How do I get root access from shell? When I'm trying to use `su` I get:

```
    default@default-laptop:~/home/default$ su
    Password: 
    su: Authentication error
    default@default-laptop:~/home/default$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

su wants the root password, if you're running Ubuntu that will be scrambled. Try `sudo -s -H` or `sudo su -` and give your user password.

Comment: take note if you're not in the sudo ring, this will be useless as well.

Comment: If your user account is an "Administrator", the sudo su works great. Sometimes I use a series of sudo [command], and sometimes I just sudo su and then enter the [command]. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, an easier way is to use the following command:

```
$ sudo -s
```

This tells **sudo** to launch a shell.  Make sure that you are in the **admin** group on Ubuntu.  You can check your groups by using:

```
$ groups
```

If you are not in the group, you can add yourself by using the following

```
$ sudo gpasswd -a <username> admin
```

Also to note, on a default Ubuntu install, root's password will be the same password as the default user.

Answer (score 1):

On a default Ubuntu installation you cannot su as root. You can use sudo to launch any command you need.

You can also do

```
sudo passwd
```

after entering your password you will be able to give root a password. After you will be able to su as root.

Comment: This is not recommended as this poses security threats. I recommend leaving the root password "unknown."

Comment: It's also wrong, you should do "sudo passwd" not "su passwd".

Answer (score 1):

On non-Ubuntu systems, you will need to ensure that your username is part of the "wheel" group in the /etc/group file. See "man group" for syntax, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**su** requires the root password

**sudo su** will accomplish the same thing, with your own password (not root's) - but you have to be set up properly in advance to do this.

Some distro's like Ubuntu give the *first user full sudo access*.  Others, like Debian, require you to *set up the root account* during the install.